# iOS Swift: How to create .zip file from my document directory files

Tags: swift, dictionary, zip, document, unzip

In my application want to capture the log message, and write the log message in text file, and zip the text file attached thought mail.

Here my code:

```
let file = "APPLog.txt" //this is the file. we will write to and read from it
        let text = "MyLog messages"//just a text
        if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)
            //writing
            do {
                try text.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
            }
            catch {/* error handling here */}
            //reading
            do {
                let readtxt = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
                print("readtxt",readtxt)
            }
            catch {/* error handling here */}
        }
```

In document directory "APPLog.txt" this text file is created. How can i zip this text file and attached thought mail. Help me. Thanks advance.

Comment: https://github.com/marmelroy/Zip

Comment: In this github local file only option to zip. How can i zip document directory files files help me.

Comment: without using pod is there any way to achive this..